# Can anyone see a problem with the way I'm redirecting the output of these processes?

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

Alright so I'm having a problem with threading. I'm instantiating a new "ExecuteThread" class, and firing off a new thread to run the method "ThreadProccess" in that new reference, multiple times asynchronously. 
Now all the process start and run and finish asynchronously PERFECTLY. The problem is, I need to redirect those processes' output. As soon as I uncomment the line that is commented down there, everything goes out of wack and starts running consecutively, and returning the wrong elapsed times and such. (The elapsed times were correct before). And I need this line because it is where it stores the output. 
Can anyone see a problem with the way I'm redirecting these outputs?

```
public class ExecuteThread
{
    private string exePath;
    private string gPath;
    private string filePath;
    private string tPath;

    private Dictionary<string, string> gReference;
    private Entry entry;
    private startNextThread callBackDelegate;
    private ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
    private PInfo pInfo;
    private Process filePExe;

    public ExecuteThread(Entry entry, string exe, Dictionary<string, string> gReference, startNextThread callBack)
    {
        pInfo = new PInfo();
        this.entry = entry;
        this.gReference = gReference;
        exePath = exe;
        callBackDelegate = callBack;

        getPInfo();
        createStartInfo();
        InstantiateProcess();
    }

    private void getPInfo()
    {
        GetGPath();
        filePath = entry.ResolveSourcePath(entry);
        tPath = entry.ResolveArtifactsTagsPath(entry);
    }

    private void GetGPath()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.fileType))
        {
            if (g.ContainsKey(entry.fileType))
                gPath = gReference[entry.fileType];
                return;        
        }
        gPath = null;
    }

    private void createStartInfo()
    {
        startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath);
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = gPath + " " + filePath + " " + tPath;
    }

    private void InstantiateProcess()
    {
        filePExe = new Process();
        filePExe.StartInfo = startInfo;
        filePExe.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    private void Parse()
    {
        try
        {
            this.filePExe.Start();
            this.fileParserExe.WaitForExit();
            //this.pInfo.additionalMessage += filePExe.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            this.filePExe.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            parseInfo.additionalMessage += e.ToString();
            parseInfo.additionalMessage += "Could not locate single file p executable: " + exePath;
        }

    }

    public void ThreadProcess()
    {
        this.pInfo.fileName = entry.fileName;
        this.pInfo.startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Parse();
        this.pInfo.endTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.pInfo.SetElapsedTime();

        if (this.callBackDelegate != null)
        {
            this.callBackDelegate(this.pInfo);
        }
    }
}

public class PInfo
{
    public string fileName;
    public DateTime startTime;
    public DateTime endTime;
    public string ElapsedTime;
    public string additionalMessage = "";

    public void SetElapsedTime()
    {
        TimeSpan elapsedTime;
        elapsedTime = this.endTime.Subtract(this.startTime);
        ElapsedTime = string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss.fff}", elapsedTime); 
    }

}
//How I'm starting each thread
if (entryQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            ExecuteThread eT = new ExecuteThread(entryQueue.Dequeue(), exe, gReference,
                new startNextThread(startNextThread));

            Thread newThread = new Thread(eT.ThreadProcess);
            newThread.Start();
        }
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the PInfo or ParsingInfo classes.

Comment: That was a misstype there is just the PInfo class. Fixed it and pinfo is in there

Answer (score 3):

You should put the line you commented **before** the call to `WaitForExit`. For more info, see the *Remarks* section of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx).

Additionally, you should use the Stopwatch class to measure the duration of an operation. See the [*Remarks* section of `DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) for more info.

**UPDATE:**
You could try using the async reading of the output stream to see whether this helps. For this, change your `Parse` method like this:

```
this.filePExe.OutputDataReceived += 
    (s, e) => this.pInfo.additionalMessage += e.Data + Environment.NewLine;
this.filePExe.Start();
this.filePExe.BeginOutputReadLine();
this.filePExe.WaitForExit();
this.filePExe.Close();
```

Comment: This did not fix it. Moved it up one line.

Comment: I will do that. But I'm pretty positive that the timespan measurement technique I'm using is not the problem.

Comment: @Joey: Me too. Please see the update and try it. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Updated. And your update didn't change anything :/
EDIT: How I'm starting each thread is near the bottom of the code.

Comment: @Joey: In my update, what will resolve your problem? (a) Commenting out the complete first line that assigns the event handler to `OutputDataReceived`? (b) Replacing the event handler of `OutputDataReceived` with the following: `(s, e) => {};`? (c) Commenting out the line with `BeginOutputReadLine();`?

Comment: Commenting out the beginoutputreadline resolved the issue, but there is still no output coming through.

Comment: @Joey: Obviously - sorry. For me it looks like an inherent limitation in reading the standard output stream. It looks like you can only read the output stream of one process at a time. However, I can't find anything like this in the documentation.

Comment: Yep. This is the only way that you can get information from an executable correct? I just want to get information back like did it parse, did it fail ect. The only way I thought of doing this was in the executable, output this information to the console, then redirect the output. Is there another way?

Comment: @Joey: If you have control over the other application, there are a lot more possibilities: You can use inter process communication like WCF for example.

Comment: Could you link me to a site that explains this? I don't know if I have control. I created the application if that helps. But could you link me to a good site that explains WCF?

Comment: @Joey: If you created the application, you have control over it ;-) I can't suggest any WCF tutorial, because I haven't used one. Just google and you will find enough.

Comment: Alright thank you so much for all your help! I have one more question, what do you do if your question gets buried (no one else views it) like this one. Do you repost? I won't repost this one because I have a solution just curious.

Comment: @Joey: I think editing it pushes it back up: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature. Another possibility is to [set a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) which requires 75 rep. Additionally, on the right hand side, you can see, how many views your question got. Yours got like 47 and only 1 answer. This means that the question is either too long or unclear. Yours is too long - the sample code could have been reduced significantly by extracting it into a console application and cutting away anything that isn't needed(cont.)

Comment: Yea. The problem with shortening my question is I get an overflow of people yelling "UNCLEAR QUESTION VAGUE CANNOT BE ANSWERED".

Comment: (cont.) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Joey: Please see the edit of my comment. Your question should be short and still precise and containing anything to answer it.